# How to read file using Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

i have a function i am trying to read a file from the same directory it is showing promise pending what needs to be fixed here

index.js

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'Accounts.txt');
async function ReadFile() {   
  try {
    let data = await fs.readFile(path.join(filePath));
    data = String(data)
    return data;
 } catch(e) {
   console.log(e);
 }
```

Console

```
READING FILE>>>> Promise { <pending> }
[0] (node:6379) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
```

Comment: you need to use `fs.readFileSync(...)`

Comment: readFileSync isn't exported from fs promises.

Comment: You need to resolve it either by using another await inside An [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) like: `(async function () {
  console.log(await ReadFile());
})();`

Comment: using `then()` like that : `ReadFile().then((x) => console.log(x));`